# IE6 min-width issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I know IE6 does not support min-width, but I've tried using the following to get ie to play nicely but it's not really working..!

```
nav.top ul li {
width: expression(document.body.clientWidth < 60? "61px" : document.body.clientWidth > 120? "121px" : "auto");
}
```

The HTML for this looks like

```
...
<li><a>text here</a></li>
<li><a>text here</a></li>
<li><a>text here</a></li>
...
```

Using the expression above, all the li's are the same width, which for navigation is not ideal, especially as longer ones can be added dynamically by the user.

The HTML above is only partial, I'll try to post more when I'm at my computer...!

Ideally I'm after a CSS solution as the expression above lives in a conditional spreadsheet and would make things easier.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: For the record: http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9223114/Microsoft_declares_demise_of_IE6_in_U.S.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit unclear.

What are you trying to achieve on the nav? Are you just trying to get a navigation bar?

would this help you?

```
nav.top ul li {
   display:inline-block;
}

.oldie nav.top ul li {
   zoom: 1;
   *display: inline; 
}
```

Comment: I am trying to ensure that the navigation works in ie6. At the moment if long words are used they wrap over 2 lines, something that does not happen when min-width is used..

Comment: please provide a fiddle or a more detailed description of the navigation you wish to achieve.  maybe a url showing what this navigation looks like!

from what you've described, my answer will work.

Comment: `code`
<nav class="top">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="/">Events</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="/">Marketing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
     <a href="/">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="/">About the Programme</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
`code`

This is the HTML, adding anything longer than one word, breaks the layout in IE6. I tested with your css and the layout is still broken

Comment: DUDE!  I know what a nav list is but I have no idea how you want it to look!

PLEASE PROVIDE A JAVASCRIPT FIDDLE and edit your opening question.

http://jsfiddle.net/